# Porque compila mal dev C++ si escribo con espacios el nombre del archivo?

Tags: c++, dev-c++, compilar, compilacion

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int num; 
 
main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,""); //ES PARA QUE ME RECONOZCA LAS TILDES
    cout<<"Ingrese usuario un numero"<<endl;
    cin>>num;
    
    if(num % 2 == 0){
        cout<<"El numero es par";
    }else{
        cout<<"El numero es impar";
    }
}
```

nada fuera del lo desconocido, ocurre que compilo y no se ejecuta el else con el mensaje "el numero es impar", originalmente el archivo se llamaba "numero par y impar.cpp", el profesor me resolvió la duda, y me hizo cambiarle el nombre a "parImpar.cpp", compile y si se ejecuto el else como debería.

pero me quedo la duda del porque ocurre esto. eso es lo que pregunto aquí.

Answer (score 1):

El nombre del archivo fuente no debería influir de ningún modo en el comportamiento del programa que resulte al compilar.

Pero es posible que (dependiendo de qué compilador uses y cómo lo uses) la compilación falle, pues un espacio en el nombre puede ser interpretado como "final" del nombre de archivo. Así, por ejemplo, si compilases con `g++` usando el siguiente comando:

```bash
$ g++ numero par y impar.cpp
```

obtendrías un error de que el fichero `numero` no existe, pues el espacio ha sido usado por el shell como separador, por lo que `g++` estaría recibiendo en realidad varios parámetros que consideraría nombres de ficheros separados.

Ese problema es fácil de arreglar poniendo comillas alrededor del nombre del fichero:

```bash
$ g++ "numero par y impar.cpp"
```

Entonces ¿qué ha pasado en tu caso? Solo puedo aventurarlo, pues no tenemos información suficiente.

Mi hipótesis es que inicialmente habías puesto un nombre de fichero sin espacios, y ese compilaba sin problemas, pero el código no estaba terminado. No tenía la parte del `else`. Más adelante renombraste el fichero como "numero par y impar.cpp" y a partir de ese punto ya no compilaba correctamente pero no te diste cuenta. Entonces cuando ejecutabas el programa, en realidad estabas ejecutando la versión previa que había sido compilada con éxito. Por eso, por más cambios que hicieras en el código fuente, a la hora de ejecutarlo no veías esos cambios, pues en realidad se estaba ejecutando la versión anterior.

Al renombrarlo de nuevo y quitar los espacios, ya compiló correctamente y pudiste ver los cambios realizados.